# Process pst file from apache Pig

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig, jobs

i am  trying to process pst file from apache Pig.  Do i need to write User define function to read pst?.How can I process/extracts pst using Pig way 
Is there any UDF ,library available in java which I can use in my Pig script. Any help would be great-full .

Thanks,
Vamshikrishna

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware that there is support for .pst files so probably yes, you need to write an UDF and more precisely a [LOAD](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.13.0/udf.html%23load-store-functions) UDF.